# Error in metasem, tssem2, "operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types"

Tags: r

I try to estimate parameters in a meta-analytical path model, where A -> B -> C (full mediation) based on a list of correlation matrices in `metaSem`.

My `A1` matrix is as follows:

```
A1 <- create.mxMatrix(c(0, 0, 0,
                                indep2med, 0, 0,
                                0, med2dep, 0),
                              type="Full", byrow=TRUE, ncol=3, nrow=3,
                              as.mxMatrix=TRUE)
          dimnames(A1)[[1]] <- dimnames(A1)[[2]] <- variable.labels
```

My `S1` matrix is as follows:

```
S1 <- create.mxMatrix(c("1", 0, 0,
                                0, ".1*e2", 0,
                                0, 0, ".1*e3"),
                              type="Full", byrow=TRUE, ncol=3, nrow=3,
                              as.mxMatrix=TRUE)
          dimnames(S1)[[1]] <- dimnames(S1)[[2]] <- variable.labels
```

All is fine when I use the standard settings in estimating the pooled correlation matrix and estimating the model parameters using:

```
fit1 <- tssem1(data.list$data,data.list$n,method = "REM", RE.type = "Diag")
fit2 <- tssem2(fit1,Amatrix=A1,Smatrix=S1)
```

However, if I set diag.constraints="TRUE" in tssem2, that is `fit2 <- tssem2(fit1,Amatrix=A1,Smatrix=S1,diag.constraints="TRUE")` as is recommended for mediation models, I get an error:

> Error in diag.constraints & (sum(Constraints) > 0) :    operations are
>   possible only for numeric, logical or complex types

What do I do wrong? Moreover, why do I need to set diag.constraints="TRUE"?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`A1` should generate an error. The correct syntax for `A1` is:

```
A1 <- create.mxMatrix(c(0, 0, 0,
                        "0*indep2med", 0, 0,
                        0, "0*med2dep", 0),
                        type="Full", byrow=TRUE, ncol=3, nrow=3, 
                        as.mxMatrix=TRUE)
```

The other syntax seems correct to me. By the way, `diag.constraints="TRUE"` is not required in `tssem2()` any more.

Comment: Thank you; I forgot to include the '0*' here, the problem was that I did not know that the argument 'diag.constraints='true' is not needed anymore.